# Session State not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is supposed to display the information I entered into the Text Boxes here.

```
protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string vacations = Session["Vacations"] as string;
            string hobbies = Session["Hobbies"] as string;
            string classes = Session["Classes"] as string;

            lblDisplay.Text = "Your favorite vacations spots are: " + vacations;
            lblDisplay.Text = "Your hobbies are: " + hobbies;
            lblDisplay.Text = "Your IT Classes are: " + classes;
        }
```

Here is the basic code that i use in my other pages to store the information in session state. All my pages are the same, only different names.

```
protected void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Vacations"] = txtVacations.Text;

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

I have researched what to do, and from what I have researched, this should work. But it obviously is not working. When i run the page and click on the button, the information that i entered into the textboxes on previous pages is no stored. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is your session configured in your `Web.config` file?

Comment: @Lloyd I have added the web.config file

Comment: from MSDN's page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5(v=vs.100).aspx, `A Web Forms page or class that has access to the current request context using the Current property in an ASP.NET application that has session state enabled.` are you accessing the same request context or class?

Comment: @Travis See this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web.config should have something like this in it:

```
<sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc" />
```

Timeout = The time the session will be held before being abandoned/removed. If this is too low then it could be the reasons that things disappear. 20 mins is the default timeout for a session in IIS

Mode = Where the session is held, be it in memory or on a sql state server etc. You prob want InProc.

InProc = Session state is in process with an ASP.NET worker process. This is what you will want to use in this situation I'm guessing.